# Creating reference to a Fortran type

Tags: types, fortran

If I have the following Fortran code, using a previously defined array of TYPEs:

```
subroutine
use mModule, only: myTypeObjects

TYPE (myType) :: myTypeReference

myTypeReference = myTypeObjects(1)

end
```

Does myTypeReference make a reference to the TYPE object, or does it do a copy?

Comment: This is not valid Fortran. Please post a *compilable* code snippet. Maybe then it becomes clear what you mean...

Comment: Sorry I made a syntax error with the declaration of myTypeReference. Assume myType has been elsewhere

Comment: I still don't have a clue what you mean... and it's still not valid Fortran. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short little program, which outputs 1, 2.
Thus, this is not a reference in the python/C++ way that you are thinking.
`a` is it's own object, thus the implicit assignment operator does a default copy. This assignment operator can be overridden for a particular type though.

Fortran doesn't have "references" that the programmer can manipulate directly. While it's true that all function arguments are passed by reference unless explicitly stated, this is hidden from the programmer.

If you want reference like behaviour, Fortran does have "pointers" that can do something similar. Fortran pointers are different from "C" pointers though, so read up on them first!

```
program blah
implicit none

type :: blah_t
  integer :: val
end type

type(blah_t) :: a,b

b%val = 2
a = b

a%val = 1

write(*,*) a,b

end program blah
```